# Sample Space Issues - Raffle Drawing

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a practice problem and I'm a bit confused on what I should be defining as my sample space for the following problem:

> Your local town is raffling off one car, one motorcycle, and one bicycle. There are $236$ tickets (numbered $1-236$), and they will draw three numbers, in order, to receive the three prizes.
>
> Part A: Describe a sample space of this experiment.
>
> Part B: John holds five tickets, denoted by the set $J = \{14, 43, 111, 168, 227\}$. Describe the event "John wins the car" as a set, then find the propability of this event. You may assume the first ticket drawn corresponds to the car.
>
> Part C: Describe the event "John wins at least one prize" as a set. Find the probablity of this event.

Are there any context clues here that say tickets are put back into the raffle if they win? For Part A, I defined by sample space to be $S = \{n \in N: 1 \le n \le 236\}$. Since all tickets are equally likely to be drawn, $P(x) = \frac{1}{236}$ for all $x \in S$. If tickets can be put back into the raffle, then wouldn't my sample space have to be a $S^3$ product of that above set?

Moving onto part B, since we may assume the car is the first prize drawn, the event is just John's tickets, $E = \{14, 43, 111, 168, 227\}$. Since all outcomes are equally likely, we have $P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|S|} = \frac{5}{236}$.

Moving onto part c, I realized that my sample space is probably not sufficient. I would need to figure out the number of ways John wins NO prizes (the complement of my event), and subtract that off from $1.$ Unless I'm missing something, I can't do this correctly with a sample space of $236$.

I think I'm on the right track, but missing something in my idea of the sample space. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I assume these tickets are drawn without replacement.  that is, a ticket can win at most one prize.  If so, your sample space is wrong as it includes duplicates and triplicates.

Comment: Let $A = \{n \in N : 1 \le n \le 236\}$. I defined my sample space then as $S = \{(x,y,z) \in$ $A$ x $A$ x $A : x \neq y, x \neq z, y \neq z\}$ I believe this contains what I'm looking for then. How do I find $|S|$? Is it just $236 * 235 * 234$? All outcomes are equally likely, so is my probability function just $P(x) = \frac{1}{236 * 235 * 234}$?

Comment: Your calculation of $|S|$ is good.  That probability makes sense if you want the probability of predicting the right three numbers (in order).  To do $B$...as the choice of the car winner is uniform John's probability is just $\frac 5{236}$.  To do $C$ it is easier to compute the probability that John wins nothing and then subtract that from $1$.

Comment: How can I (simply) define a set for the event in problem $C$?

Comment: As I said, I think it's easier to work with the complement: the event $C^*$ in which John wins nothing.  Then you just need the first number to miss (prob. $=\frac {233}{236}$) and the second one to miss ($\frac {232}{235}$) and so on.  Multiply those five fractions and subtract from $1$.

Comment: But isn't the event set described by "John wins nothing" and "John wins at least one prize" different? I understand why this is useful to find the probability of this event, but not how it helps me describe the actual set of the event.

Comment: In the universe of possible outcomes for John, the set you want is the complement of the set in which John loses.  Phrased differently:  the intersection of John's numbers with the winning triple can have $0,1,2,3$ elements.  You want the ones other than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

A possible description of a sample space $S$ is
$$
S = \left\{(y,x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \{1,\ldots,236\}\times\{0,1\}^3 \mid \sum_{i=1}^{3} x_i\le 1 \forall y \,\,\& \sum_{y=1}^{236} x_i = 1 \forall i \right\}
$$
Imagine it as a grid where each number $y$ is associated with three check boxes.We then have that box $i$ corresponds to that number being the winning ticket for prize $i$.